# How to change the font color selected option using angularjs not with css?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Iam unable to change the font-color of selected option using ng-class and ng-style for static dropdown without ng-repeat.

```
 <select ng-model="myColor">
    <option value="">none</option>
    <option value="red" ng-style="{'color':myColor}">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

Please refer below JSfiddle link

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ehxcuop/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Styling a built in `<select>` is severely limited. (and this question has nothing to do with angular)

Comment: @ChrisG  but I need with angularjs not with css.

Comment: Doesn't matter, angular styles are just CSS expressed as JS object. You cannot magically style the built-in `<select>` using angular. If you want a styled `<select>`, use something like [this](https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/).

Comment: localStorage.getItem('itemVerified') == 'True'